# Get first and last email of the day from outlook PST file using powershell

Tags: powershell, search, outlook, pst

I need to generate a report, using an Outlook PST file, that shows details of the first and last email sent each day with the recipients, etc. This would need to cover a specific timeframe, such as the past month.

How would one go about this? Perhaps run a query for the first email of each day and then another query for the last email of each day?

If you have any ideas, that would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Richard

Comment: This is a programmer's Q&A site, not a free code-generation service. That is, you need to demonstrate some effort at solving the problem on your own rather than just asking others to write the code for you.

Comment: Bill's right.  The process to follow is to take your problem, break it into logical parts, and then try to attach them together with your language of choice.  When you run into pieces of that which don't work, you'll be able to research those little pieces and get an answer.  If something still doesn't work, ask for help.  I know this isn't as fast as something like this, but maybe if you want it quick and effortless, ask a freelance site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've removed my comments that show my solution as I'm not convinced stack overflow is the place for them, seeing the reception my question got. Contact me by email if you want the code, free of course. Cheers